# Is there a way to collect data of what my friends/people in Discord server play?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am in student organization which has a pretty popular Discord server. We would like to organize a LAN party, however, we do not know what games our members like the most- as to maximize the attendance.

I was thinking I could write a bot to scrape names of the games people in the server play, and also their frequency. This could give us an idea of what games to run on the LAN party.

So my question is, **Is there a way how to log what people play and how much?** Is this even possible to with Discord API?

*Concerning the legal side of this stunt, whether or not, let`s pretend it`s fine.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I suppose you'd like to collect the current activities of all members of the guild, just to get an initial picture of which games are played the most.

E.g., you could implement a **bot command** that once run in a guild channel, creates a dictionary with the names of the different games as keys and the number of members that are currently playing them as values. For instance:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

games = {}

# The following command iterates through the list of members in the guild, analyzes their activities
# and counts the number of members that play each game.
# The data is collected in the games dictionary and then is printed out in the console.

@bot.command()
async def activities(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        for activity in member.activities:
            if isinstance(activity, discord.Game):
                if activity not in games.keys():
                    games[activity] = 0
                games[activity] += 1

    for game, count in games.items():
        print(f"{game.name}: {count}")

bot.run("bot_token_here")
```

Then you may want to keep the dictionary updated according to changes in the members activities. This can be done through a **bot event**:

```
# The following event is called whenever a member changes their activities. 
# If there is a new activity and it's a game, the relevant counter is increased in games dict.
# If any activity was removed and it was a game, the counter is decreased.

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    old_activities = before.activities
    new_activities = after.activities
    for activity in new_activities:
        if activity not in old_activities and isinstance(activity, discord.Game):
            if activity not in games.keys():
                games[activity] = 0
            games[activity] += 1

    for activity in old_activities:
        if activity not in new_activities and isinstance(activity, discord.Game):
            games[activity] -= 1
```

Here I used a dictionary to collect the data, but it is advisable to use an external file to permanently write the data, or rather a database, otherwise all the information will be lost as soon as the script is interrupted.

## Edit:

As kindly suggested by Łukasz Kwieciński, the **intents** for presences and for members must be specified as they are not included in the default intents and are required respectively to manage activities and to enable events involving guild members.

It should be noted that to use these privileged intents you must activate the **privileged gateway intents** option in the bot tab of the application, in the developer portal.

Comment: One thing, intents. Both presences and members are required which you didn't add to your example

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Added, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by using the [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update) event.
You just keep track of when their activity changes to a certain game, log the time, and log the time when they stop playing or go offline.